# Swift NavBar to TabBar prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to send data via prepareforsegue to a TabBarController that is embedded in a NavigationBarController.

This was my last attempt and it did not work

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destinationViewController = tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ProgressStartViewController // or whatever tab index you're trying to access
    destinationViewController.departureAirportLineChart = "data1"
    destinationViewController.arrivalAirportLineChart = "data2"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what problem you are facing ?

Comment: A tab bar controller shouldn't be embedded in a navigation controller.